# Concatenate HTMLScriptElement

Tags: javascript

Given that i have the following:

```
var el, main;

main = _.findWhere(this.widget.snippets, {
  name: "main"
});

el = document.createElement("script");

el.setAttribute("data-require", value.name + "@*");

el.setAttribute("data-semver", a.semver);

el.setAttribute("src", a.scripts);

console.log(el + main.body);
/*
  [object HTMLScriptElement]
  <div bb-breadcrumb></div>
  <div bb-content></div>
 */
```

I am trying to append my newly created script to my body. However it keeps returning `[object HTMLScriptElement]` is there not a way that i convert this to a string which will then allow me to do the concatenation.

Further update:

The value of the var `main` is an object that looks like the following:

```
$$hashKey: "018"
body: "<div breadcrumb></div>↵<div content></div>↵"
file_extension: "html"
file_name: "main"
isEdited: false
name: "main"
```

So with this at hand. You will see that I create an `<script></script>` element for which outputs:

`<script data-require=​"jquery@*" data-semver=​"2.1.1" src=​"/​/​cdnjs.cloudflare.com/​ajax/​libs/​jquery/​2.1.1/​jquery.min.js">​</script>​`

Now towards the end of the code sample I initially provided I want to concatenate that  tag and append it to the `main.body` so the end output would look like:

```
<script data-require=​"jquery@*" data-semver=​"2.1.1" src=​"/​/​cdnjs.cloudflare.com/​ajax/​libs/​jquery/​2.1.1/​jquery.min.js">​</script>​
  <div breadcrumb></div> 
  <divcontent></div>
```

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of important context. There are undeclared variables used and the types of your objects are not known. Can you provide some more detail and produce a self-contained example? Perhaps a JSFiddle would help to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @TomFenech i haave updated my question which should provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `main.body` is a string, you cannot concatenate an object to it. However, you can use the [`.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML) property of your newly created element, which is the HTML representation:

```
el = document.createElement("script");
el.setAttribute("data-require", value.name + "@*");
el.setAttribute("data-semver", a.semver);
el.setAttribute("src", a.scripts);
main.body = el.outerHTML + main.body;
console.log(main.body)
```

Output:

```
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="/​/​cdnjs.cloudflare.com/​ajax/​libs/​jquery/​2.1.1/​jquery.min.js"></script><div bb-breadcrumb></div>↵<div bb-content></div>↵
```

[See it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m0vuums5/1/)

Comment: Please see my update to my question. I get precisely what your code does. It finds the element test, create a new div you put some content in that div and then insert it before the id `test`

Comment: Please see my updated answer and accompanying JSFiddle, I believe that it does what you want.

Comment: `outerHTML` was exactly what i needed. Think a better explanation would've been to just say i need a dump of the HTMLScript element as a string

Comment: is there not a way to format it so the div is on a separate line to the script?

Comment: Sure, just put a newline character in between: `main.body = el.outerHTML+"\n"+main.body;`